# How to run my own Ripple RPC server (full node)?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways

I'm following this manual: https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#installation-on-ubuntu-with-alien and getting error below.

```
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://mirrors.ripple.com/ripple-repo-el7.rpm
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
Retrieving https://mirrors.ripple.com/ripple-repo-el7.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    package ripple-repo-1-2.el7.centos.noarch is already installed
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ yumdownloader --enablerepo=ripple-stable --releasever=el7 rippled
rippled-0.70.2-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm                         | 8.5 MB     00:01     
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ https://mirrors.ripple.com/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-ripple-release && rpm -K rippled*.rpm
bash: https://mirrors.ripple.com/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-ripple-release: No such file or directory
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ sudo rpm --import https://mirrors.ripple.com/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-ripple-release && rpm -K rippled*.rpm
rippled-0.70.2-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm: rsa sha1 (md5) pgp md5 OK
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ sudo alien -i --scripts rippled*.rpm && rm rippled*.rpm
Package build failed. Here's the log:
dh_testdir
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_installdirs
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name debian -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r -i cp -a {} debian/rippled
dh_compress
dh_makeshlibs
dh_installdeb
dh_shlibdeps
dh_gencontrol
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb --build debian/rippled .. returned exit code 2
debian/rules:17: recipe for target 'binary-arch' failed
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 1
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ chmod 755 
bitcoin-abe/                      rippled-0.70.2-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ chmod 755 
bitcoin-abe/                      rippled-0.70.2-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ chmod 755 rippled-0.70.2-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm 
ix@pwrg:/media/ix/ledgers/.src$ sudo alien -i --scripts rippled*.rpm && rm rippled*.rpm
Package build failed. Here's the log:
dh_testdir
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_installdirs
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name debian -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r -i cp -a {} debian/rippled
dh_compress
dh_makeshlibs
dh_installdeb
dh_shlibdeps
dh_gencontrol
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb --build debian/rippled .. returned exit code 2
debian/rules:17: recipe for target 'binary-arch' failed
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 1
```

How to fix the error? Am I right that rippled allows me to run full rippled rpc server like bitcoind?

Answer (score 2):

> error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)

Could it be a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

use below command:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 <directory-path>
```